# Meaning of still used in the sentence

Tags: adverbs

What is the meaning of **still** used in the following sentence

[The revised draft merely says students may change one or more of their three languages in Grade 6 or 7, “so long as they **still** demonstrate proficiency in three languages (one language at the literature level) in their modular Board examinations some time during secondary school”.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/crisis-defused/article27429380.ece)

I think without **still** it conveys the same meaning.

Comment: **Still** here means **continue to**. As you say, omitting **still** makes little difference to the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"Continue to"

Without still, the sentence would have a slightly different meaning. The students could have once demonstrated proficiency and therefore would qualify. Still implies they need an ongoing proficiency.

Please see the adverb definition in the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/still) for more info/examples.